# Google script Store the value of var getLastRow();

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a basic Google script to copy and paste google forms submissions from response sheet to another sheet for calcs ect ,to save keep copying the whole range of rows . I would like to store the last value of getlastRow() and store as a  var prevRow.

Next time the script is run I can by subtracting the difference of  old and new rows.I can then copy&paste  only from  the new  data (response) I received .

So basically  I need to know a BASIC METHOD  to  store a value and recall it next time the script is run.
Kind regards

Comment: you can save old value in file in Google drive and recall it by reading next time.

Answer (score 0):

Basic method:
Store the value in a cell. If the cell is hidden, styled or just off the screen then your user probably won't mess with it.

Better method:
Use the [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/).  It stores values in your document and you can read them back later on.  I use it for storing metadata about a document and have found it very effective.

To save a value:

```
var documentProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
documentProperties.setProperty("lastRow", lastRow);
```

To read it back:

```
var documentProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
var lastRow = documentProperties.getProperty("lastRow");
```